# Problem in character control "Character can't jump"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games, gamecontroller

I am practicing with creating a 2D-Game and I write the C#-script code but my character can't jump.

I try to replace "Space" with "UpArrow" that also didn't work.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && onGround)
 {
 rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumppower);
 }
```

Nothing Happen.
Character can'r move Right and Left but not jump.

Comment: a few points what value is jumppower? is onGround true? have you added some statements to check its running your command? that velocity could be not what you intended...

Comment: Change `GetKey` to `GetKeyDown` and check that `onGround` is returning true

Comment: Also where are you calling this inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some items to start with:

1. make sure onGroundis true. => add a `Debug.Log($"is on ground {onGround}")` before the if and check it.
2. Make sure the code is in the Update() loop (you can set it also in FixedUpdate, but update is better)

Then I see a logic issue. This is what happens in your code:

- you're on the ground
- you add velocity and move up
- you're no more on the ground
- the if fails so vertical velocity stops because you're no more on the ground
- player falls back

To solve this replace this line:

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumppower);
```

With this:

```
rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumppower), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```